# Creating hyperlinks in HTML table using Perl

Tags: html, perl

I am using the module `HTML::Template` to create a formatted table like this (using array `@rows`):

```
my $tmpl = HTML::Template->new(filehandle => \*DATA);
$tmpl->param(ROWS => \@rows); 
print $tmpl->output;

__DATA__ 
<table border="1"> 
<TMPL_LOOP ROWS> 
  <tr> 
  <TMPL_LOOP CELLS> 
    <td><TMPL_VAR CELL></td> 
  </TMPL_LOOP>
  </tr> 
</TMPL_LOOP>
</table>
```

However I now want to create hyperlinks of some of the elements of the table. The address the element 
is linked to depends on the text of that cell as well as the column of the table..
**Example:**
If a row has the elements `Home, Office, Travel, Play` then 
I would like them to be linked to `www.mywebsite.com/Home`, `www.mywebsite2.com/Office` and `www.mywebsite3.com/Play` with no hyperlink for `Travel`.
How can I create such hyperlinks in the HTML::Template created table?

Comment: Couldn't you just do something like `<td><a href="mywebsite.com/<TMPL_VAR CELL>"><TMPL_VAR CELL></a></td>`

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** Rewritten answer to use [Template::Toolkit](http://metacpan.org/module/Template%3a%3aToolkit) based upon the updated question and comments by the question's author.

```
# Your app sets up whatever data structure it wants to pass to the tempalte, for example,
my @rows = [
    [ # cells in row #1
        { url => 'www.mywebsite.com/Home', label => 'Home' },
        { url => 'www.mywebsite2.com/Office', label => 'Office' },
    ],
    [ # cells in row #2
        { url => 'www.mywebsite3.com/Play', label => 'Play' },
        { label => 'Travel' },
    ],
];

# No need to print, prints to STDOUT automatically by default
my $tmpl = Template->new;
$tmpl->process(\*DATA, { rows => \@rows })
    || die $tmpl->error();

__DATA__ 
<table border="1">
[% FOR row IN rows %] 
  <tr> 
  [% FOR cell IN row %] 
    <td>
    [% IF cell.url %]
      <a href="http://[% cell.url | url %]">[% cell.label | html %]</a>
    [% ELSE %]
      [% cell.label | html %]
    [% END %]
    </td> 
  [% END %]
  </tr> 
[% END %]
</table>
```

Template::Toolkit has many of the same capabilities as Perl (actually exactly the same if you enable Perl blocks, but I don't recommend that).

Inside of each `[% %]` you put in a directive. If there's no directive and no assignment performed using `=`, that block is treated as a variable lookup and that value passed into your template is interpolated into the text there. When doing a variable lookup, you can descend through an entire complex data structure using periods to separate the lookups. For example,

```
[% rows.0.0.label %]
```

inserted in the example above, would output "Home".

The `| url` and `| html` notation shown above adds filters that will clean up the output to make sure the values inside the `[% %]` blocks are output as proper URLs or HTML (generally avoiding XSS and other output format errors).

Template Toolkit is a little fuzzy and imprecise about how it does things sometime, even less strict than Perl, so you have to be a little careful sometimes. It can also be a bit of a performance problem, especially if you call `process()` lots of times in your app (embedding templates one in another tends to be quite a bit faster). However, it does a reasonably good job at most template problems and the interface is not too scary if you need to work with web designers.

If you use Template::Toolkit, I strongly recommend reading through [the tutorial](https://metacpan.org/module/Template%3a%3aManual%3a%3aIntro) to get a feel for it.

**Original Answer:**

Lone Shepherd's comment is the answer:

I am using the module `HTML::Template` to create a formatted table like this (using array `@rows`):

```
my $tmpl = HTML::Template->new(filehandle => \*DATA);
$tmpl->param(ROWS => \@rows); 
print $tmpl->output;

__DATA__ 
<table border="1"> 
<TMPL_LOOP ROWS> 
  <tr> 
  <TMPL_LOOP CELLS> 
    <td><a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/<TMPL_VAR CELL ESCAPE=HTML>"><TMPL_VAR CELL ESCAPE=HTML></a></td> 
  </TMPL_LOOP>
  </tr> 
</TMPL_LOOP>
</table>
```

Just add the HTML for your hyperlinks. According to the documentation for [HTML::Template](http://metacpan.org/module/HTML%3a%3aTemplate), you can place the `<TMPL_VAR ...>` bits inside of attributes.

As a side note, adding `ESCAPE=HTML` is a good idea as well unless you're certain you've already sanitized your output (prevents things like [cross-site scripting attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29) on your web application).

Comment: @LoneShepherd Oops, I did not make myself clear enough. Please see the edited question.

Comment: That's more than I know about HTML::Template. I usually use [Template::Toolkit](http://metacpan.org/module/Template::Toolkit) or something else. Someone else will have to answer how to do lookup tables or more complicated conditions unless you want a Template::Toolkit answer.

Comment: Ok, I am ready to use another module if `HTML::Template` cannot do the job. But you will have to explain a bit, I have never used `Template::Toolkit` before.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the explanation! In the meantime I managed a workaround using javascript. I'll give this module a try now.